# Excel VBA Loop to insert rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, insert, rowcount

Firstly the Data.

```
A          B
Type 15    5
Type 2     7
Type 3     9
```

I need to create a loop, that starts at B1 and inserts a number of rows based on the cell value of B.

I found the below code , but it does not loop, and i need the next cell it checks to be the result of the first cell(5) + 1 in order for it to be correct.

**

- Result should be :

**

```
A          B
Type 1     5


Type 2     7





Type 3     9

etc.
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: We can't see the code that you are mentioning. Also if Column A will have values starting with `Type` and 1,2,3, etc than  why use VBA where you can simply use formula?

Comment: Try to screenshot the input and result so it will be obvious what exactly you mean. About the code, I don't think it needs to be mentioned again that we cannot see it.

Comment: @ManishChristian the op want the spaces that is why the results should have the extra spaces.

Comment: Its bit confusing to understand what actually op wants to achieve. Rolled back to your edit.

Comment: Loop backwards, then use offset to set the range in which you want to add extra rows.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up the question in the first place, however i have found the answer.

Please see below.

```
Sub InsertRowsIf()
Dim lr As Long, R As Range, i As Long
lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set R = Range("B1", "B" & lr)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = R.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If IsNumeric(R.Cells(i, 1).Value) And Not IsEmpty(R.Cells(i, 1)) Then
    R.Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(R.Cells(i, 1).Value).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next i
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub